# How to add line chart on candlesticks chart in plotly python

Tags: python, plotly, linechart, plotly-python, candlestick-chart

I have a candlesticks chart of some stock in plotly python. The picture is below:
[image: Candlestick Chart]

This is working fine. But when I tried to add a line chart. Everything scattered. The picture is below:
[image: With Line Chart.]

Is there any way to make it correct?
Below is my code:

```
response = response.json()['values']
ts = pd.DataFrame.from_records(response)
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=ts['datetime'],
                                         open=ts['open'],
                                         high=ts['high'],
                                         low=ts['low'],
                                         close=ts['close'],
                                         line=dict(width=1))])

 response_ti = response_ti.json()['values']
 df_ti = pd.DataFrame.from_records(response_ti)
 fig.add_trace(go.Line(x=df_ti['datetime'],y=df_ti[technical_indicator],))
```

Answer (score 0):

- recreating with public APIs

  1. change column names so your plotting code is not changed
  2. assuming a technical indicator
  3. ignoring deprecated warning with `go.Line()`
- graph creates without issues you note.  I can only assume that

  - the **datetime** column is not uniform between your two dataframes
  - version issues, this is created with **plotly** 5.2.1

```
import yfinance as yf
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from stockstats import StockDataFrame

appl = yf.Ticker("AAPL")

# get stock info
ts = (
    appl.history("1y")
    .reset_index()
    .pipe(lambda d: d.rename(columns={c: c.lower() if c != "Date" else "datetime" for c in d.columns}))
)

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=ts['datetime'],
                                         open=ts['open'],
                                         high=ts['high'],
                                         low=ts['low'],
                                         close=ts['close'],
                                         line=dict(width=1))])


df_ti = StockDataFrame.retype(ts)
technical_indicator = "close_10_sma"
fig.add_trace(go.Line(x=df_ti['datetime'],y=df_ti[technical_indicator],))
```

[image]